# Check string or JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I need help. 
If userID is right. JSONObject is

```
{
  "info": {
    "name": "Guest",
    "age": "18"
  }
}
```

If userID is wrong. JSONObject is

```
{
  "info":"wrong"
}
```

My code:

```
if (!(resultObject.getString("info").contains("name"))) {
   String strImg = resultObject.getString("info");
   System.out.println("str response: " + strImg);
} else {
   JSONParse jsonParse = new JSONParse();
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resultObject.getString("info"));
   onSuccess(jsonParse.convertJsonToInformation(json));
}
```

But doesn't work. I don't know how to parse it

Comment: The second you run getString, you start parsing it. Check if there's an `isString` method or something (depends on the JSON lib)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a consistent Json format rather than using a dynamic format. So your processing will be always same. You can first check for the status. If the status is "ok" you can then consume the info Json node.

Example for a correct info:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "info": {
    "name": "Guest",
    "age": "18"
  }
}
```

Example for a wrong info:

```
{
  "status": "wrong",
  "info": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(response).optJSONObject("info");
            if(dataObject == null){
                System.out.println("str response: " + json.optString("info"));
            } else {
                JSONObject jsonSuccess = new JSONObject(json.getString("info"));
            }
```